# Difference between MariaDB Server and Maria DB Enterprise?

Tags: mariadb

https://mariadb.com/pricing

From what I gather, the difference between "free" MariaDB and enterprise MariaDB, is solely around certification, support, and plugins. Is this correct? Is the server itself identical in these two instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB comes in a few different forms:

**MariaDB** is free and includes: Access all the features of MariaDB Server

**MariaDB Enterprise Subscription** includes a number of other features and is **priced per server**.

To look at the high-level features available see: https://mariadb.com/pricing